# Chromecast custom receiver adding to queue from receiver

Tags: chromecast

i am trying to create a slideshow type app that will play both videos and photos. i am populating the array of the items from a network request performed by the chromecast after it gets a unique id from the sender. i am them trying to add these items to the media queue from the receiver but this error is showing up when i try.

Unexpected command, player is in IDLE state so the media session ID is not valid yet

any advice on what i am doing wrong, or logs that i can provide to help identify the issue? thanks in advance.

Comment: answered my own question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881391/chromecast-receiver-how-to-load-media-without-explicit-cast-sender-request/35929564#35929564