# Chromecast Receiver App - Unexpected command, player is in IDLE state

Tags: javascript, ios, chromecast, google-cast

I am using the cast reference player sample code to develop a receiver application. I am using the cast message bus to send a JSON string that will launch my media.

So in my `player.html`, I init the `cast message bus`. When I `receive JSON` of the media that I want to play, I init `player.js` from `player.html` like so:

```
//receive message to play -> pass media through
var player = document.getElementById('player');
new sampleplayer.CastPlayer(player).start();
```

then in my `player.js`:

```
sampleplayer.CastPlayer.prototype.start = function() {
  var self = this;
  var message = //JSON string
  this.load(JSON.parse(message));

  var millisecondsToWait = 8000;
  setTimeout(function() {
    //Pause Works
    self.mediaElement_.pause();
  }, millisecondsToWait);

  var millisecondsToWait = 10000;
  setTimeout(function() {
    //Play Works
    self.mediaElement_.play();
  }, millisecondsToWait);
};
```

I am able to launch the media, I can play/ pause the media with the code above.

When I try use the play/ pause button on my remote control, I get the following error: 
`[cast.receiver.MediaManager] Unexpected command, player is in IDLE state so the media session ID is not valid yet`.

I also don't get any of the `PlayState` updates that I was previously getting.

I believe I am not initialising something right, but I'm not sure what. Does anyone know of a good starting point for me? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881391/chromecast-receiver-how-to-load-media-without-explicit-cast-sender-request/35929564

Comment: @Mr.Rebot, I saw that question alright, it is very similar, but I wasn't able to use the answer to my advantage.

Comment: If the question is the same, it's a duplicate.  If you can, please elaborate on how the answer to the linked question does not solve your problem.

Comment: The answer linked assumes that I am going to queue items to play first via a sender application. I am trying to performing everything on the receiver side. There is no `queueLoadItems` on the cast receiver sdk, only the `iOS sender sdk`. i.e. linked answer needs a sender interaction, mine needs do it all on it's own.

Comment: @Mark117 Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @masterwok, no I did not. If you ever figure it out, please let me know. I hate leaving an unanswered question.

Comment: @Mark117 So I found the solution for my problem, but I'm not sure if we were hitting the same thing. For me, media was playing on the receiver, but the sender media controls weren't responding/getting media info. It turns out that calling RemoteMediaClient.load() is required to properly setup the session. However, you can still handle media loading on the receiver by overriding MediaManager.load() with an empty function. This way, MediaManager.load() doesn't overwrite media you already have configured when you "load" the session on the sender.

Comment: @masterwok, I'll try give that a go in the next day or so. You can add it as an answer if you want and I'll accept it if it works.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this can help someone.

I could successfully load and start a video with the PlayerManger using `playerManager.load(loadRequestData)` and `playerManager.play()`. However, once I stopped using `playerManager.stop()` and then tried to play again, I used to get this error:

```
[cast.receiver.MediaManager] Unexpected command, player is in IDLE state so the media session ID is not valid yet
```

This happens because the `playerManager.stop()` method unloads the video from the tag.

To fix this behaviour, just check if a video is loaded before playing.

Example:

```
if (isNaN(playerManager.getDurationSec())) {
  // the player has been stopped, then I reload the video
  // Load with autoplay: playerManager.load(loadRequestData)

  // create some queue items
  const item = new cast.framework.messages.QueueItem()
  item.media = new cast.framework.messages.MediaInformation()
  item.media.contentId = '/movie.mp4'
  const items = [item]

  // Create a new queue with media.
  let queueData = new cast.framework.messages.QueueData()
  queueData.items = items

  // [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Media or QueueData is mandatory
  const loadRequestData = new cast.framework.messages.LoadRequestData()
  loadRequestData.queueData = queueData
  cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance()
    .getPlayerManager().load(loadRequestData)
}
else {
  playerManager.play()
}
```