# Custom CAF receiver how to handle idle statement for displaying splash screen

Tags: casting, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I'm building a custom Chromecast receiver based on the [CAF SDK][1]. I've tried to set the receiver application in `IDLE` state mode for handling the splash screen during the 5 minutes after the media has ended... 
I tried to use :

```
var video = document.createElement("video");
            video.classList.add('castMediaElement');
            video.style.setProperty('--splash-image', 'url("img/logo-mySplash.svg")');
            document.body.appendChild(video);

var context = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance();
context.setInactivityTimeout(300);
playerManager.addEventListener(cast.framework.events.EventType.ALL, 
    function (event) {
        switch(event.type) {
            case 'CLIP_ENDED':
               context.setApplicationState('IDLE');
               break;`
        }
    })
```

When the media ended, the receiver dispatches :

```
{type: "CLIP_ENDED", currentMediaTime: 2673.986261, endedReason: "END_OF_STREAM"}
{type: "MEDIA_FINISHED", currentMediaTime: 2673.986261, endedReason: "END_OF_STREAM"}
```

and sends error to debug console :

```
[ 32.846s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Unexpected command, player is in IDLE state so the media session ID is not valid yet
```

I can't find any documentation about this issue. Thanks anyway for your answers.

Comment: Regarding your error, you have the same problem with another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366352/chromecast-receiver-app-unexpected-command-player-is-in-idle-state), you may also refer to this another post as the latter is was redirected [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881391/chromecast-receiver-how-to-load-media-without-explicit-cast-sender-request/35929564).

Answer (score 0):

The `context.setApplicationState` simply updates the application's `statusText`.  See: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.CastReceiverContext#setApplicationState.

What you probably want to do is add a listener to the `playerDataBinder` on `cast.framework.ui.PlayerDataEventType.STATE_CHANGED` event.  This way you can make your idle screen visible whenever the `state` property changes.

Also, in order to get the full advantage of using CAF you probably want to to use the `cast-media-player` element.  Additional information on the benefits of using this element instead of a custom video element can be found here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_features